# jest: how to test console.log haveBeenCalled with a subset of expected value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

i'm testing a function which adds a logging and timing functionality to any function which passed to it, so i have a problem to test the timing section:
my functions:

```
//utils.js
export const util_sum = (x: number = 0, y: number = 0): number => x + y;
export const util_getTime = () => performance.now();
export const util_addTimeLogger = (fn: Function) => {
  let t_start = util_getTime();
  const beautify = JSON.stringify;
  return (...args: any[]) => {
    console.log(`entering ${fn.name}: ${beautify(args, null, 2)}`);
    try {
      const valueToReturn = fn(...args);
      console.log(`normal exiting ${fn.name}: ${beautify(valueToReturn, null, 2)}`);
      console.log(`--->total execution time:${util_getTime() - t_start}ms`);
      return valueToReturn;
    } catch (thrownError) {
      console.log(`exception thrown ${fn.name}: threw ${thrownError}--->time:${util_getTime() - t_start}ms`);
      throw thrownError;
    }
  }
};
```

test section:

```
//util.test.js
describe("util_addTimeLogger", () => {
  it("should add logging functionality with time to any functions", () => {
    console.log = jest.fn();
    const entering_msg = 'entering util_sum: [\n' +
    '  1,\n' +
    '  2\n' +
    ']';
    const normal_msg = 'normal exiting util_sum: 3';
    const total_time ='--->total execution time:0.47500000800937414ms';
    const loggedSum = util_addTimeLogger(util_sum);
    loggedSum(1,2);
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entering_msg);
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(normal_msg);
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(total_time);
  });
});
```

my problem is in the third test, which is :

> expect(console.log).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(total_time.slice());

i couldnt find a matcher like tohaveBeencalledContainOf or subSetOf like in document: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html

so is there any way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution for this situations, based on jest https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectstringcontainingstring:

> expect.stringContaining(string)

expect.stringContaining(string) matches the received value if it is a string that contains the exact expected string.

> expect.stringMatching(string | regexp)

expect.stringMatching(string | regexp) matches the received value if it is a string that matches the expected string or regular expression.

```
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringMatching(/--->total execution time:0.*/));
```

or

```
const total_time ='--->total execution time:0.';
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining(total_time));
```

**update:**
for the sake of completeness which other developer may have similar problem in testing error section. we can throw error, just consider that you should  use try catch to send the error thrown to the right part:

```
  it("should throw error with fn.name and it's calculated time", function () {
    const errorThrown = util_addTimeLogger(() => {
      throw new TypeError();
    });
    const error_msg = "exception thrown : threw TypeError--->time:";
    try {
      errorThrown();
    }
    catch (error) {
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("entering : []");
      expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringContaining(error_msg));
    }
  });
```